# What index will be good for performance while inserting rows/updating rows in table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

A table has an Primary Key Clustered index.
Deadlocks occurs frequently on the above table resulting loss of data.
While inserting rows or updating row what index will be good to add which has better performance?

Table :
ID Int Identity,
EntityID Int,
EntityName nvarchar(200),
MeasuringID Int,
Cratedon datetime

Primary Key Clustered : ID

Records gets inserted very frequantly everytime into the table.

** Any isolation levels or locks to be placed in the Stored Procs of Insert and update?

Comment: No index. A heap has the best `INSERT` performance. `UPDATE` is a bifferent ballgame, altogether

Comment: You didn't show the table.  Is the primary key a composite key?  Data in a clustered index is stored in order on disk so if you have a primary key that has new entries that aren't guaranteed to be in order (e.g. an email address or an identity number) you could expect to see poor insert performance.

Comment: Without knowing all the details, it's very hard to answer a question like this. Add more information please.

Comment: @Raj: heap should be used only if one really knows its pro's and con's. Apart from UPDATE, DELETE will perform poor, and it is same even with INSERT if nonclustetred index is used. And what about fragmentation? If you really don't want to query that structure at all (almost) use naked heap.

Comment: What deadlock are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a very complicated question especially when related to index performance, but before calling in a consultant, just ask your SQL server, don't just blindly create these, they just give you an indication.
Also keep your fill factor in mind, this might affect your insert performance favorably.
Requires 2008 and up and will generate code for an offline rebuild. Impact over about 1k denotes attention required

```
    USE <YourDBName>
    SELECT (avg_total_user_cost * avg_user_impact/100.0) * (user_scans +user_seeks ) Impact
    , [Table] = [statement]
    , [CreateIndexStatement] = 'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_' + sys.objects.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT  + '_' 
    + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ISNULL(mid.equality_columns,'')+ISNULL(mid.inequality_columns,''), '[', ''), ']',''), ', ','_') + ' ON ' + [statement] 
    + REPLACE(' ( ' + IsNull(mid.equality_columns, '')
    + CASE WHEN mid.inequality_columns IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CASE WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ',' END + mid.inequality_columns END + ' ASC ) ' ,',',' ASC ,') + CASE WHEN mid.included_columns IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ')' END 
    + 'WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON,FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY];'
    , mid.equality_columns
    , mid.inequality_columns
    , mid.included_columns
    FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats AS migs 
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups AS mig ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle 
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details AS mid ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects WITH (nolock) ON mid.OBJECT_ID = sys.objects.OBJECT_ID 
    WHERE (migs.group_handle IN (SELECT TOP (500) group_handle FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats WITH (nolock) ORDER BY (avg_total_user_cost * avg_user_impact) * (user_seeks + user_scans) DESC))  
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(sys.objects.OBJECT_ID, 'isusertable') = 1 
    ORDER BY Impact DESC, [CreateIndexStatement] DESC ;
```

Comment: @Adrian..
Thanks for the qry..
Added more detail in the question..Pl suggest if any...
Thanks in advance